# CLI start a scan on a specific file

Tags: deepsecurity

Is it possible to cli, API or somehow start a scan on a specific file? I have a customer who wants to use this in Veeam v10 Secure Restore (https://helpcenter.veeam.com/docs/backup/vsphere/av_scan_xml.html?ver=100)

Comment: Is this a question about Deep Security or Veeam v10 Secure Restore?

Comment: Deep Secuity. The question is if I can make (and howto) an API or something to be called by the Veeam Secure Restore feature

Answer (score 0):

thanks for clarifying to Scott that this is a question about Deep Security capabilities. Looking at that link, it sounds like you want to tell Deep Security to scan a particular set of files from a backup. Deep Security does not have an API to start a scan on a specific file or folder. The closest thing to that would be using the Scheduled Tasks API to start a Malware Scan on an entire computer. You may want to consider other Trend Micro products for this use case.

P.S. I work for Trend Micro in R&D for Deep Security.

Comment: Which product would allow for such file specific scan?